# WatchKit Complication pushes app identifier / certificate (WWDC20)

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, pushkit, apple-watch-complication

In the session "Keep you complication up to date" (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10049/), they explain how to create a proper certificate for your complication pushes (at min 16:55)

They explain that you would have to create an app identifier with your bundle identifier and ending in watchkitapp.complication (example: bundleId.watchkitapp.complication).

If I want to create such an app identifier, I get the following error on the developer portal ({bundleId} is a placeholder for the actual bundle id):

> An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
> Identifier '{bundleId}.watchkitapp.complication' is not available.
> Please enter a different string.

Does anyone experience the same? How to fix this?